# how to create Android Switch Programmatically Dynamically

Tags: android

I hope my layout will be this :

[image]

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        Switch sw = new Switch(this);
        sw.setChecked(false);
        ll.addView(sw);
    }

    this.setContentView(sv);
```

I want to create a textView is left side , and switch is right side,just like my post. I think layout is

-LinearLayout(horizontal)

```
   - TextView              -Switch
```

what do I do ? thanks.

Comment: Creating So many dynamic views could impact your performance. I would suggest you to use RecyclerView. And if you still want to use the same You have to create another child view with TextView on the Left and Switch on the right and add that view to your LinearLayout ll.

Comment: In fact , I know recyclerView will be the best way , but I am stuck at pass value to adapter , so I am try to create switch programmatically.my json file is : "key":"aa", "value":false , there will be 20 counts.aa is TextView , false is switch.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
              Switch sw = new Switch(this);
              sw.setChecked(false);
              sw.setText(String);  //that' right
              ll.addView(sw);
         }
```